# Why Map getters look different from Map.Entry getters?

Tags: java

Who is responsible for this? Why `Map.Entry` are `getKey()` and `getValue()` but for `Map` they are `keys()` and `values()` without "get"? Why their naming is not consistent?

Comment: [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) doesn’t have a `keys()` method, but it does have [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--). This and `values()` are not direct getters, since they involve creating a new `Collection` and copying data.

Comment: What is a map, it is a collection. A collection of what, of map entries.

Comment: yea, it's `Map.keySet()` and `Map.values()`and `Map.entrySet()`, but you are right: the naming pattern is "not consistent", but maybe due to the fact, that `key` and `value` are "real (full) properties" of `Map.Entry`, and the rest just "transient" methods...

Comment: it's also *not* `getHashCode()`, but `hashCode()` ;)

Comment: ... *and* (i should make it answer :) *there is* `Map.Entry#setValue(V val)` ...there is *no*  `Map.Entry#setKey(K key)`, but just to the fact, that `key` is a *final* property....and there is no equivalent like `setHashCode(int hc), setValues(Collection c), setKeys(...)`,  which backs my thesis of "real properties"  vs. "transient methods".

Answer (score 0):

In the Map, you are retrieving a Set so the method signature is

> public Set java.utils.Map#keys();

and the method for Map.Entry is :

> public K java.utils.Map.Entry#getKey()

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can request all map keys or values via a collection using its keys() or values() function.
You can iterate through a map by its EntrySet, where you can have all the elements one by one and all these elements will have a key and value accessible with getKey() and getValue(). So different approach to work with maps.
Not sure if I can interpret this correctly: "Who is responsible for this?"